# What should I choose: Meteor or MeanJS?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, meteor, mean-stack, meanjs

I wanted to get into full-stack JS development. I was about to start with the usual MEAN stack (MeanJS). I stumbled upon these articles:

http://wiki.dandascalescu.com/essays/why_meteor http://wiki.dandascalescu.com/essays/meteor_js_vs_the_mean_stack/

That are convincing. I am really confused how to get started. What are the pros and cons of using a frontend-backend-database framework like meteor over the conventional MEAN?

Comment: I think this question is too broad. Also, the answer depends on the kind of application you wanna do.

Answer (score 3):

Due to the nature of the question, I'll try to answer it broadly. After using the MEAN stack for over 2 years and Meteor for a few months, I much prefer Meteor.

If you're just starting, Meteor has amazingly simple conventions. Try the [angular-meteor tutorial](http://angular-meteor.com/tutorial) to get started. Meteor offers one line installs, perhaps most notably including user authentication. You get the power of observables & latency compensation as a default.

The MEAN stack requires much more configuration and setup, as well as a strong developer foundation in Node.js. You have to do the work, but it may be worth it to understand the full stack. Much of what Express handles in dozens of lines of code can be handled in one line of code in Meteor.

Having said that, it is sometimes difficult to hack together Angular with Meteor. For example, I'm currently having difficulty using the new-angular-router with overlapping Meteor conventions. Consider MEAN has a much longer trusted history and wider support.

Comment: I know it's a very opinionated question, but I would just add 2 interesting videos a saw recently about that subject: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u_Q4nfRxj-M  , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RObEcZhiXF8    , about the new-angular-router, please submit an issue to angular-meteor and I'm sure we can solve it very quickly ;)

Comment: As the new-angular-router isn't fully complete yet, I suppose it's worth waiting. On a related note, I just finished an article on using [Angular with Meteor](http://www.shmck.com/angular-meteor/).

Answer (score 2):

I think you are going to get a lot of opinionated answers, but to be honest every user is different and you won't really know until you try each out. I took a look at all the tutorials that were available for the ones that interested me.

ReactJs:
I was never a fan of reactjs, until the 3rd time I went through the tutorial, and thought this is kind of easy to get the hang of :
http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html

ReactJs is a framework by facebook and is doing pretty well. It works by updating the DOM and the syntax reminds me of that of programming a game. It uses states and props.

AngularJS:

I didn't prefer angular js as much because I didn't really give it much of a try (atleast more than twice). I was hypocritical about it. I thought of it as too much to remember and the tutorial I tried with it was this one :

https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial/

I think it is a great tutorial to get you into the stack. I can't say much about it but Angular 2.0 is coming out soon.

MeteorJS:

I never gave it a full go, but it looked interesting and from what I read, it was mobile friendly and great for single page app. Recently I've been following this tutorial:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-a-slack-clone-in-meteor-js-getting-started.

This is the next project I'm going to try to do in Reactjs(in meteor first).

I think its all really preference and you should just give all of it whirl. Some might be better at some functionality then others, some may be more syntax friendly, some may just be easier to use. All depends on the type of person you are.

Answer (score 1):

Since Meteor is built upon NodeJS, it may be obvious that it was created to enhance development over the MEAN stack.

Meteor relieves the pain of writing hundreds of lines of code to accomplish a simple real time app, for example.

So if your question begins with "I wanted to get into full-stack JS development...", I strongly recommend you Meteor over MEAN.

At the end of the day: 
"Meteor will be the JavaScript framework that will rule them all"